# what is operation in salesforce component in mule ESB?

Tags: salesforce, mule, anypoint-studio

I could see operation field in salesforce component.

There are so many operations in salesforce, please can anybody provide a link or description about each operation in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Salesforce Connector Reference, especially at the [Operations](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/salesforce-connector-reference#operations) section.